# Python Splitting issue

Tags: python

Im trying to get the SPF records for a list of domains from a file.The File will contain inputs like,

```
Input_Domains.txt

1,box.com
2,blah.com
3,....
```

Script :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

    import sys
    import socket
    import dns.resolver
    import re


    def getspf (domain):
       answers = dns.resolver.query(domain, 'TXT')
       for rdata in answers:
         for txt_string in rdata.strings:
           if txt_string.startswith('v=spf1'):
             return txt_string.replace('v=spf1','')

    with open('Input_Domains.txt','r') as f:
         full_spf=""
         spf_rec=""
         for line in f:
            x=line.split(',')
            app_id=x[0]
            domains=x[1]
            try:

               full_spf+=getspf(domains.strip())+"\n"
               #output=full_spf
               #o_spf=x[0]+","+full_spf+=getspf(x.strip())+"\n"
            except Exception:
                 pass
    my_file=open("out_spf.txt","w")
    my_file.write(full_spf)
    my_file.close()
```

Now,The output i get is just the records of a particular domain.I would like to get `App_ID` followed by spf record for a domain.Any suggestion on this please ?

```
Example Output :
1,SPF records of box.com...
2,spf recors of blah.com....
......
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem of your code, is that you're writing only once when you should be writing for each line.

```
with open('Input_Domains.txt','r') as f:
    with open('Output_spf.txt', 'w') as g:
        for line in f:
            # ...
            g.write(full_spf)
```

Comment: Yes,Thanks Mate ! Solved it @greut